# How to get the $(this) to work in JQueryUI autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EZ56N/137/) example

I have trouble getting the `$(this)` to work in the source function with jQueryUI autocomplete.
The console shows that the search input isn't able to get its data attribute 'name' before sending out an Ajax request. Is there any way to pass the variable "name" to `data`?

```
$('.input').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var name = $(this).data('name');
        console.log(name);
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                'q': request.term,
                'field': name
            },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data.query.results.json.json, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.name,
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).val(ui.item.label);
        $(this).val(ui.item.label);
    },
    open: function () {
        $(this).autocomplete("widget").width(400)
    }
});
```

Comment: i think, if you console log `$(this)` you will get the autocomplete object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `this.element` to access corresponding input element. `this` points to the autocomplete instance itself:

```
var name = $(this.element).data('name');
```